# OPenssl alert certificate unknown SSL , alert number 46

Tags: c++

I am writing my own https server. But I faced such a problem:
[image]

I make own certeficate use openssl.
[image]

but when i try connected i recived erorr
94390000:error:0A000416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 46

Comment: Please post code as text not screenshots. I can't tell: is this an error you're getting on your server, or in client code trying to connect to your server?

Comment: It sounds like the server just doesn't trust your client certificate. Can you debug that? Does the server have the certificate that signed the client certificate, and does it trust it?

Comment: This is server code , my client - browser.

Comment: Yes certificate self signed , and dont trusted , how make it trusted , can i off ssl check certificate , because i made this just for local using

Comment: The server needs a certificate that is the issuer for accepted client certificates, which can be self-signed, and client certificates should be signed by that. I'm not sure how to configure that in OpenSSL directly but in Apache's mod_ssl it's SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile.